@abacritt/angularx-social-login : Failed to open popup window on url
After clicking on the pop-up to choose an account, I encountered an issue. Can anyone assist with this?
Here are my configurations: :
googleLoginOptions: {
oneTapEnabled: false,
scopes: 'profile email',
},
**
Google Cloud Console Configuration:**
Authorized JavaScript origins
http://localhost
Authorized redirect URIs
http://localhost:4200
**
I am encountering this issue :**
[GSI_LOGGER]: Failed to open popup window on url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?gsiwebsdk=3&client_id=XXXXX-34e5ksdgcqnemjgt8rugar9c9u0b6kdb.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile%20email&redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttp%2Flocalhost%3A4200%3Fid%3Dauth378165&prompt=select_account&login_hint=softnach%40gmail.com&response_type=token&include_granted_scopes=true&enable_granular_consent=true. Maybe blocked by the browser?
Thanks for your help
I expect there to be no popup after selecting an account, avoiding the need to authorize a popup.
